# App ID and Bundle ID Conflict

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit my app to iTunes Connect. I created an apple ID that is the same as my bundle ID. However, when I try and export the archive of the project, it says that an app with my bundle ID already exists.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to create a new bundle ID or app ID. This can save you a lot of time, instead of debugging.